# VS Plugin to save groups of files to open together?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I was just wondering if there was a plug in for VS that anyone might know of that'd allow me to save a group of files within a solution and open them together?

The project I'm working on is a solution file with over 120 projects in it. For any given bug or feature request, a number of files from an assortment of different projects will be related and need to be modified. Then I might come back a few days later and need to make changes to a few of the files but it takes a while to navigate through this rat's nest of a solution in the Explorer pane.

I've come to just saving a text document with the full path to the files, then copy-paste each location into Windows Explorer and that automatically pulls it up in VS for me. It works, but it's time consuming and tedious and frankly just antiquated. Also tried using Excel instead of a generic text file, but that confirms *twice* that I want to open this potentially hazardous file.

It'd be really nice to have something directly in VS that links a handful of files and opens them all. I've tried searching around Google but I don't know what you'd call this to try and narrow down my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Favorite Documents](http://vlasovstudio.com/favorite-documents/) extension lets you save and open groups of files.

Comment: Awesome! I spent a while yesterday making a small app that'd just write XML files with a list of the files and launch them for me, but this is infinitely better than anything I could make :)

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with the same problem (finding individual classes/files within a ton of projects in a single solution), I've found that ReSharper's `Go to Everything/Type` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) solves my problem. No, it doesn't open all the files at once for you to modify. Instead, it finds the files for you easily without the need to search through the Solution Explorer. For me, that was enough to no longer wish for a tool that does what you're asking for.

Comment: Sadly I'm pretty sure my company won't spring for Resharper licenses, and I don't really want to spend the money on it myself.

Good to know, though.